# HtmlAgilityPack using HtmlWeb.LoadFromWebAsync does not invoke the PreRequest (or PostResponse) handler

Tags: html-agility-pack

I have some code using HtmlAgilityPack that uses the HtmlWeb PreRequest and PostResponse handlers to capture and set cookies. However, I am now converting the code to perform async requests so I converted the Load() calls to LoadFromWebAsync(). It appears the PreRequest and PostResponse handlers are not being called from LoadFromWebAsync() and the cookies are not being captured or set on subsequent requests.

Is there another way to cause cookies to be processed or am I going to have to stop using HtmlWeb and use HttpClient directly?

Comment: Fyi, there is a bug for this (https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/issues/467). It looks like the functionality does not exist at this time.